# Calling method without creating an instance

Tags: kotlin

I want to call a function in the 'static' way
i heard there isn't an equivalent for static in Kotlin
so I'm looking into a way to make it work.

```
fun main() {
var ob1 : Ob1 = Ob1()
ob1.try1()
}

class Ob1{
        fun try1() = println("try 1S")
}
```

If I use java i would just name it static than call the function directly.

Thanks on advance..

Comment: There are no static members in Kotlin - correct. There is no equivalent of static in Kotlin - this is incorrect. Kotlin authors just assumed that static members are effectively the same as regular members of a class itself or they're members of singleton object attached to a class. At least for me it makes more sense than static.

Comment: ok so i will just have to live without my static friend. thank you

Comment: Why do you need static specifically? Companion objects provides exactly the same functionality, they're identical at use-site (e.g.: `MyClass.foo = 5`) and they can even map to JVM static members for Java interop (`@JvmStatic`). They're effectively the same.

Comment: it is just help me to stay more organized for big projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define function outside class or simply define it in a companion object:

```
class Ob1{
    companion object{
        fun try1() = println("try 1S")
    }
}

fun main() {
    Ob1.try1()
}
```

Yo can read more in official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

Comment: it is limited one per class so its not as usefull as static
i think in this case i should just make an object of the class

Comment: @Avihay you can only have one companion object, but that object can have as many methods or properties as you want

Comment: Oh i tested it now. u can access each method directly in it so it is indeed useful info. thank you